# Different Outputs between Vscode/gcc and online compilers

Tags: c

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void
ft_putchar(int a)
{
    write(1, &a, 1);
}

void
control(va_list ag, const char c)
{
    if (c == 'c')
        ft_putchar(va_arg(ag, int));
}

void
ft_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ag;

    va_start(ag, format);
    int i = 0;

    while (format[i]) {
        if (format[i] == '%') {
            i++;
            control(ag, format[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else {
            write(1, &format[i], 1);
            i++;
        }
    }
    va_end(ag);
}

int
main()
{
    char a = 'Z';
    char b = 'y';

    ft_printf("mer%chaba%c", a, b);
}
```

I am trying to write `"merZhabay"` but in vscode and gcc it writes `"merZhabaZ"`. But on online compilers like python tutor and onlinegdb write `"merZhabay"`. Which compilers are right and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please format the code properly and get rid of all the syntax-failing backslash characters. Also note that `write` isn't a standard C function, so it may behave differently on various platforms. Another thing, don't hard code the file id.

Comment: Most urgent lesson to learn: code formatting. Make it a high priority for yourself to learn about good code formatting with the help of indentation, spaces and empty lines. This helps a lot to make the code readable and understandable.

Comment: Assume the compilers are right, and the code is incorrect, with *undefined behaviour* a possible reason.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> void control(va_list ag
> ```

Passing `va_list` *by value* to the function *twice* is not correct. These just are the rules [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16p3](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16p3):

> The object ap may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the va_arg macro with parameter ap, the value of ap in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the va_end macro prior to any further reference to ap

The simplest fix is to pass `va_list` by a pointer.

```
void control(va_list *ag, const char c) {
   if(c == 'c')
       ft_putchar(va_arg(*ag, int));
}
....
  control(&ag, format\[i\]);
```

Strongly consider using code formatter. Some IDEs even have internal "auto reformat" options.

Answer (score 0):

Once your `ft_printf()` passes `ag` to the `control()` function and `control()` invokes `va_arg()` on its copy, `ft_printf()` may no longer do anything with the original except pass it to `va_end()`.  Not even pass it to another call to `control()`.  Undefined behavior results when it does.

You should be able to work around that by making `control()` accept a `va_list *` instead of a `va_list`, and having `ft_printf()` pass the appropriate address, `&ag`.